# output of camera plugin in standalone gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

Dear Friends, i want to do a simple project and i need to image processing, i should say that i work with standalone version of gazebo (1.8) (without ROS), so, i inserted a camera in gazebo and i get output of it with this command:

```
> gztopic echo /gazebo/default/camera/link/camera/image
```

but i can't understand its output:

```
    time {
  sec: 17
  nsec: 449000000
}
image {
  width: 5
  height: 2
  pixel_format: 3
  step: 15
  data: "\255\273\336\250\267\333\246\264\332\246\265\332\251\267\333\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214\214"
}
```

any one can explain the output? also i set width = 5 and height=2 in SDF file of camera.
i want to know what is the pixel_format and step and order of data ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3310/output-of-camera-plugin-in-standalone-gazebo/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The data is the raw value of the pixels.
There are 30 (5*2 sets of RGB values) in the item.
From a brief look at [Image.hh](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo/blob/master/src/common/Image.hh), the format 3 is probably RGB_INT8.

The step is how long a row of data is in the image (5 pixels and 3 values for each pixel).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-06-25**:
Thank you so much, but my friend i can't understand exactly order of data? based on your explanation the first three number are for first pixel in first line and first column (or in other way the first fifteen number are for first row of image), and data printed row by row? am i right?!

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-06-25**:
That's how I interpret the data.

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-06-25**:
Thank you so much my friend.